# TokenProcessor usage in struts 2

Tags: java, struts2

I need to migrate my struts 1.1 application to struts 2. Few of my classes extend `Action`, `ActionForm` and `TokenProcessor` classes from struts 1.1. I read about how to make changes in classes which extend `Action` and `ActionForm`. But I am unable to get the information as to which class needs to be used in place of `TokenProcessor`. I am using isTokenValid(), resetToken() and saveToken() APIs from `TokenProcessor`. Hence need help regarding this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the code, not all the code have dependency to the Struts, so they could migrate as is.

Comment: In my class, I am making calls to parent class like super.resetToken(), super.saveToken() etc.

Comment: TokenHelper maybe?

Comment: I have already taken a look at this class. This cannot serve my purpose.